# По бокам приложения серые рамки возможно их как то поменять на чёрный?

Tags: android

По бокам приложения серые рамки возможно их как то поменять на чёрный ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас, наверное, какой-то фреймфорк, не нативное андроид приложение? Тогда надо смотреть как в нём это делать. Если андроид (да и в других случаях) можно попробовать прописать цвет фона в стилях. В манифесте это не прописать.

Answer (score 0):

Script

window.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";